# Looking to download historical continuous futures data on quandl

Tags: quandl

I am a relative newbie in this area, so please forgive me.

I am interested in downloading historical continuous futures data with price adjustments for gaps between contracts.  in particular, im interested in Back panama and back ratio methods of price adjustment, along with an open interest rolling rule.

when using quandl, does the free version offer price adjustments methods?  Or is it only the premium version?

so for something like ES SP minis, im interested in these symbols.

CME_ES1_OB
CME_ES1_OR

can anyone direct me to find these two historical data feeds for excel?

thanks!